# How to set stroke or del tag inside of code tag

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, outdated-information

I'm not able to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761586/1614378)

The answer is a little bit outdated. AMR is no longer supported.
I don't want to remove the entry but set <del>strike</del> around of `*AMR (Adaptive Multi-Rate, a format for speech)` inside of `<code>` tag.

I understand it will not work. What should I do? What would you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those lists aren't code. I just removed the code markdown and changed that for bullet lists.

Now you can apply strikeout with normal formatting tags, or just update the lists.

---

You can get some formatting in code blocks by using `<pre><code>` syntax.

```
It is not very pretty.
```

A bit tedious to do, so not the best thing to do. Commenting out the parts (with a nice explanation about why it's wrong/not needed anymore) that need striking out in that circumstance sounds like a better option.

Comment: You don't have to forego syntax-highlighting for that. See the duplicate.

Comment: Yep, saw that. Didn't know it worked... amended the answer.

Comment: It's very tedious, fiddly and easy to get wrong, so the conclusion is right: Do something else.